Ray Chan, Marvel art director, has died
Ray Chan, Art Director and Production Designer for Marvel Films, Dies at 56

Ray Chan, the art director and production designer for Marvel Studios who contributed to Guardians of the Galaxy, three Avengers movies, the upcoming Deadpool & Wolverine and more, has died. He was 56.

Also, apparently, owner of Memeland and 9gag.
